# Error "Local variable 'results' might be referenced before assignment"

Tags: python

I am very new to Python. I am attempting to develop a chatbot using a tutorial I found online. I have seen solutions similar to my problem, but I'm struggling to implement them. The error message I'm getting is as follows:

> Local variable 'result' might be referenced before assignment

Please see my code below.

```
def getResponse(ints, intents_json):
    tag = ints[0]['intent']
    list_of_intents = intents_json['intents']
    for i in list_of_intents:
        if(i['tag']== tag):
            result = random.choice(i['responses'])
            break
        else:
            result = "Please ask the right questions"
    return result
```

Comment: Yes, it might: what if the list is _empty_?

Comment: assign the variable result start of the function

Comment: Or make the [`else` part of the loop](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

Answer (score 0):

If you define *result* outside of the *for* loop it will resolve this issue:

```
def getResponse(ints, intents_json):
    tag = ints[0]['intent']
    list_of_intents = intents_json['intents']

    result = "Turns out that list_of_intents was actually empty"

    for i in list_of_intents:
        if(i['tag']== tag):
            result = random.choice(i['responses'])
            break
        else:
            result = "Please ask the right questions"
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
def getResponse(ints, intents_json):
    tag = ints[0]['intent']
    list_of_intents = intents_json['intents']

    result = "Turns out that list_of_intents was actually empty"

    for i in list_of_intents:
        if(i['tag']== tag):
            result = random.choice(i['responses'])
            break

    return result
```

There isn't any need to use *else* if you are defining *result* out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, even [loops can have `else` parts](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

The `else` part happens when the loop runs out the "natural" way, i.e., when there isn't any `break` to end the loop.

That means you could have something like this instead:

```
for i in list_of_intents:
    if(i['tag']== tag):
        result = random.choice(i['responses'])
        break
else:
    result = "Please ask the right questions"
```

Note the indentation of the `else`. It now belongs to the loop.

If the condition inside the loop is `True` then `result` would be assigned a random "response", and the loop ends with a valid and initialized value for `result`.

Otherwise, if the loop runs out (or the list is empty!), then `result` is once again initialized in a proper way.

Either way, at the end of the loop you will have a valid value in `result` that you can use.